# Testing to see if a function is called with Jest and Typescript, and ts-jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

So I am trying to test this code

src/helpers/CommentHelper.ts:

```
export default class CommentHelper {

    gitApiObject: GitApi.IGitApi ;

    constructor(gitApiObject: GitApi.IGitApi)
    {
        this.gitApiObject = gitApiObject;
    }

    async postComment(commentContent: string, repoId: string, pullRequestId: number): Promise<any> {
        const comment: GitInterfaces.Comment = <GitInterfaces.Comment>{content: commentContent};
        const newCommentThread: GitInterfaces.GitPullRequestCommentThread = <GitInterfaces.GitPullRequestCommentThread>{comments: [comment]}
        await this.gitApiObject.createThread(newCommentThread, repoId, pullRequestId);
    }
}
```

Here the tests:

```
import  CommentHelper  from "../helpers/CommentHelper";
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import  { GitApi, IGitApi }  from "azure-devops-node-api/GitApi";


jest.mock('../helpers/CommentHelper', () => {
    return {
      default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {})
    };
});

describe("CommentHelper Tests",  () => {
    const mockedGitApi = mocked(GitApi, true);

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockedGitApi.mockClear();
    });

    it("Check to see if the gitApiObject is called properly",  () => {
        const commentHelper = new CommentHelper(<any>mockedGitApi);
        const spy = jest.spyOn(GitApi.prototype ,'createThread')
        commentHelper.postComment("", "", 0);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

This is the error:

```
    TypeError: commentHelper.postComment is not a function

      23 |         const commentHelper = new CommentHelper(<any>mockedGitApi);
      24 |         const spy = jest.spyOn(GitApi.prototype ,'createThread')
    > 25 |         commentHelper.postComment("", "", 0);
         |                       ^
      26 |         expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      27 |     })
      28 |
```

Right now we're early in the project so the tests are extremely simple. We just want to make sure gitApiObject/createThread is called. How can I achieve this without explicitly mocking out the postComment function?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

So if I get your code right, you're currently mocking the default export of your `CommentHelper` as a function.

When accessing `postComment` you will get the response of your mock back which is currently not defined.

As I see in the other things you have provided in your example test case you want to test if `GitAPI` was called. In this case, you can't mock CommentHelper since then there is no possibility for `GitApi` to be called.

If you want to mock `CommentHelper` you have to return

```
jest.mock('../helpers/CommentHelper', () => {
    return {
      default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        postComment:jest.fn()
      }))
    };
});
```

if you just want to spy on `GitAPI` your good to go. If you don't want `GitAPI` to be called add `.mockImplementation` after your `spyOn`.

Hope this helps!